# Investigate convergence of a sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $ f_n(x)= \frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}$

Tags: uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

> Let $R \in \mathbb{R}$ with $R>1$. Investigate the sequence of functions $ (f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $$
> f_n(x)= \frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}, x\in [R, \infty)$$
> with regard to uniform convergence.

I know the definition of pointwise and uniform convergence but never seen an example how to investigate uniform convergence, therefore I have no clue how to approach such problems. I know that pointwise convergence is necessary for uniform convergence but that's it. Can someone show me how to tackle such problems?

Comment: First plot $\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$, then $\frac{x^4}{1+x^4}$, you should see a pattern, and see that all points are converging to $1$.

Comment: Usually one begins by identifying the pointwise limit (as you say it needs to exist) and then the separately address the issue of uniform convergence (although depending on how you've found a pointwise limit, you may have done most of the work by that point).  It may help to rewrite the fraction as $\frac{1+x^{2n} - 1}{1+x^{2n}} = 1 - \frac{1}{1+x^{2n}}$ but this is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necessary and sufficient condition for uniform convergence on set $A$ is
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x \in A}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=0$$
As in your case $A=[R, \infty)$ with $R \gt 1$, then $f(x)=1 $ and $|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\left|\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}-1  \right|=\frac{1}{1+x^{2n}}$. Now having supremum $\frac{1}{1+R^{2n}}$ we can obtain uniform convergence.